# How to setup gatsby on window 7 32 bit?

Tags: wordpress, windows, gatsby

I am using window 7 32 bit and I want to setup gatsby  project I got an error when I used command(gatsby new project name),

```
> pngquant-bin@6.0.0 postinstall D:\logicworldreact\node_modules\pngquant-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ‼ spawn UNKNOWN

  ‼ pngquant pre-build test failed

  I compiling from the source

  × Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
    at D:\logicworldreact\node_modules\bin-build\node_modules\execa\index.js:231:11
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)

npm WARN ts-node@9.0.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 
(node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! pngquant-bin@6.0.0 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the pngquant-bin@6.0.0 postinstall script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\ajay\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-19T06_04_46_944Z-debug.log**
```

Comment: my project is set up all file is created but after completed these error showing me and then gatsby develop is not working

Comment: According to https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-0/ Gatsby requires node 14.15 or newer, while the highest node version I can install on my 
Windows 7 is 13.14

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Gatsby (especially it's [transformers and sharps](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/gatsby-on-windows/#gatsby-plugin-sharp-requires-node-x64)) required a x64 system, so maybe you won't be able to run it unless you upgrade your machine:

> Some plugins which depend on native npm dependencies require the Node
> x64 build of Node.js. If you’re struggling to install
> `gatsby-plugin-sharp`, try installing Node x64 and removing `node_modules`
> and running npm install.

---

When dealing with Gatsby + Windows you may need to add a few commands or dependencies more, as [Gatsby's docs suggest](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/gatsby-on-windows/). Run:

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools --vs2015
```

> Upon installing this package, it downloads and installs Visual C++
> Build Tools 2015, provided free of charge by Microsoft. These tools
> are required to compile popular native modules. It will also install
> Python 2.7, configuring your machine and npm appropriately.

This is required for the image processing since the transformers and sharps of Gatsby will use it.

If the error persists, try removing your `node_modules`, your `.cache` folder and using the [tutorial's commands](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/quick-start/):

```
npm uninstall node-gyp -g
npm config set python python2.7
npm config set msvs_version 2015
npm cache clean -f
npm install

npm install -g gatsby-cli
npm init gatsby
cd gatsby-site
npm run develop
```

Comment: I have already install  npm install --global windows-build-tools --vs2015 and Visual C++ Build Tools 2015

Comment: Next time provide that kind of information before. Have you removed the node_modules and installed them again? I think you will have some issues if your system is 32 bit, I thought they will be unsupported. Your node version may be incompatible...